# Knockout: Can't get specific value from observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, undefined, client-side, ko.observablearray

I created array with data about some music albums in viewmodel. I can use this array in foreach loop (for example) but I can't display only one value from this array.

My viewmodel:

```
function CD(data) {
    this.Author = ko.observable(data.Author);
    this.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    this.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
    this.Label = ko.observable(data.Label);
    this.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
}

function NewsListViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.newsList = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("/music/news", function (allData) {
        var mapped = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new CD(item) });
        self.newsList(mapped);
    });

    self.oneObject = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.newsList()[0].Title;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new NewsListViewModel());
});
```

And how I used it in html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: newsList">
     <li data-bind="text: Title"></li>
     <li data-bind="text: Author"></li>
     <li data-bind="text: Price"></li>
     <li data-bind="text: Label"></li>
</ul>
```

This works perfectly. But if I trying additionally display one value:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: newsList">
     <li data-bind="text: Title"></li>
     <li data-bind="text: Author"></li>
     <li data-bind="text: Price"></li>
     <li data-bind="text: Label"></li>
</ul>
...
<p data-bind="text: oneObject"</p>
```

it dosen't working, firebug thrown error:

> Type error: self.newsList()[0].Title is undefined

Why I cannot get one specific value but I can display whole list?

PS. Code `<p data-bind="text: newsList()[0].Title"</p>` didn't works too.

Comment: Side note: There's never any reason to write `ko.observableArray([])`. Just `ko.observableArray()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because `$.getJSON` is **asynchronous**.

So when your computed is declared your items are not necessary ready in the `newsList` so there is no first element what you could access.

So you need to check in your computed that your `newsList` is not empty (anyway your server could also return an empty list so it is always good to have this check) and only then access the first element:

```
self.oneObject = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.newsList().length > 0)
        return self.newsList()[0].Title();
    return 'no title yet';
});
```

Note: you need also write `.Title()` to get its value because `Title` is an observable.

Comment: It's not just the async issue. KO calls the computed function immediately when you define it, so that it can set up the dependency chain for it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Because the OP anyway wants to first element the array should not be empty and checking the `self.newsList().length` creates the dependency. There is no problem with the computed function executed immediately because `self.newsList` already declared and exists before the computed is declared.

Comment: The solution is fine. My problem was with the opening sentence, but looking at the OP's code again, it does apply.

Comment: @nemesv: it make sense! Thanks for explains and solution. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems with your code:

1. `$.getJSON` is asynchronous so `self.newsList` is empty when it's accessed by Knockout for the first time. Which in turn means that `self.newsList[0]` is undefined.
2. `return self.newsList()[0].Title;` in the computed observable doesn't return the value you want it to return. It should be `return self.newsList()[0].Title();`
3. You don't have to reinvent the wheel, there is the mapping plugin which you can use to map the data: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html